# mysql where field is different - null is not selected

Tags: mysql

I am doing a select on my DB with:

```
SELECT * FROM `projects` where customer_id = 37 and project_status != 'Closed'
```

I have normally 4 records:

```
project_name     project_status
project A        Open
project B        Closed
project C        NULL
project D        NULL
```

So with my select statement, I should see normally 3 records, A, C and D but I only see A. I guess this is because of something like if it is null it doesn't include but normally I should have NULL different than Closed so it should give me those records.

How can I make sure I get them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`NULL` comparisons almost always return `NULL` -- which is treated as false.  You have two options:

```
WHERE customer_id = 37 AND (project_status <> 'Closed' OR project_status IS NULL)
```

Or:

```
WHERE customer_id = 37 AND (NOT project_status <=> 'Closed')
```

`<=>` is the `NULL`-safe equality operator (described [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to)).  The ANSI standard version is called `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM`.